# WordPress Logo url

Tags: wordpress, url, yoothemes

I am trying to change the logo url for my WordPress site but cannot find a way to do it. I am using YooTheme and going through settings there's just a way to insert logos but not change url. Trying to make all my links relative but the logo is the last thing remaining.

Answer (score 1):

There are actually multiple way to change the logo in WordPress theme.

First:

```
Appearance -> Customize -> Header options
```

Second:

```
Appearance -> Theme Option -> Header options
```

Third: If you donot find any of above option working then try this one. But you should have propery knowledge for php. [Warning: You may loss your website structure]

```
Appearance -> Theme Editor -> header.php
```

Here find `img` tag with `alt` logo. You can simply make it simply by updating `src`of your logo.